# ggplot2-scale_colour_manual and scale_shape manual issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to combine 4 colors (red, blue, green and black) with 4 different shapes (shape numbers 15,16,17,19). Is this possible to assign these combinations? I did it using the code below and while the color changes the shape did not.

This is the code until now:

```
Lplot<- ggplot(totdt, aes(x=X1, y=Y2, color = Sp, fill=Sp)) + geom_polygon(data=zone2, alpha=.1)  + geom_point(size = 3)  
Lplot<- Lplot+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16,17,19, 15,16,17,19, 15,16,17,19, 15,16,17,19 ))
Lplot<- Lplot+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "black","red", "blue", "green", "black","red", "blue", "green", "black","red", "blue", "green", "black","red" ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `shape` aesthetic to be used with `scale_shape_manual`. For instance:

```
data('"mtcars"')
cars <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear, cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% summarise(n = n())

ggplot(cars, aes(x = gear, y = n)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = cyl)) + geom_point(aes(shape = cyl)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 17)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue', 'green'))
```

Comment: What I did is the same as you suggest just in a modular way.

Comment: Are you sure? Your example sets the `fill` aesthetic, not the `shape`? Otherwise I'm afraid I don't get your question right..

Comment: Even when I remove the fill it will not work. The colors change the shapes does not.

Comment: Did you remove the fill *and* add the shape-aesthetic? Could you perhaps provider a self-contained example, with data and all, that doesn't provide the preferred result?